# How to express obligation in the past

Tags: difference, phrase-request, past-tense

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37598/difference-between-should-and-must) and answer shows the difference between "must have" and "should have" in the past.

> They must have told the Police
>
> They should have told the Police

As I got, using ***must*** conveys a logical necessity and  ***should*** means a moral/right thing to do. Then, how could I say such a sentence to convey obligation? I mean to say they were obliged or forced to do something? Is it actually applicable for a past sentence?

Comment: If you want to show *'force'*, use 'had'. They **had** to tell the police.

Comment: I don't think either of your suggestions fit your requirements. Keep it simple and use "They had to tell the police".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They must have told the police

This means that it looks like that the police was told some time before. "X must have [verb]" means that the situation looks like that X did [verb].

> They should have told the police

This means that they **did not** tell the police **yet**, but the situation would have been better *if* they did tell the police. In general, "X should have [verb]" can mean that if X did [verb] at that past situation, whatever happened would turn out better.

They don't necessarily mean past obligation!

For obligations in the past, I would use

> They **had to** tell the police.